Expectation of spectral norm of a diagonal stochastic matrix
There is a diagonal matrix $G(t)\in R^{M\times M}$ where the diagonal elements are independent Bernoulli stochastic variables, satisfying $\mathbb{E}(g_i(t) = 1) = b$, and $ \mathbb{E}(g_i(t) = 0) = 1 - b$, $i=1,2,...,M$.
My question is, what is the expectation of spectral norm of $G(t)$. Intuitively, it is   $\mathbb{E}(\Vert G(t)\Vert)=1-(1-b)^M$, but I am not very sure.
Thanks a lot.

The spectral norm is just the maximal singular value, and since your matrix is already diagonal with 0 and 1 for diagonal entries, the spectral norm is 1 if one of the entries is 1 and 0 in case your matrix is 0. The probability that all the diagonal entries are 0 is $(1-b)^M$, and at least one of them equals 1 with probability $1-(1-b)^M$, thus indeed the expected value for the spectral norm is $1\cdot(1-(1-b)^M)+0\cdot(1-b)^M = 1-(1-b)^M$, as you correctly noted.
